# Not able to launch Microsoft Edge Browser in Selenium 3

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am trying to launch Microsoft Edge Browser using Selenium 3; but it is throwing the below error in the console and browser is not launched.

```
May 17, 2017 2:47:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1073741515 (Exit value: -1073741515)
FAILED: launch
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'PRABODH', ip: '192.168.207.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver
```

Below is the code snipped I used:

```
 String DriverPath=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\"+"Drivers";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", DriverPath+"//"+"MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.edge();
        driver = new EdgeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Hello");
```

I also tried to launch the browser in simpler way as shown below, but no luck.

```
String DriverPath=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\"+"Drivers";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", DriverPath+"//"+"MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Hello");
```

This is simple Java project and the piece of code is used in a Testng class.

Edge Version used :

Microsoft Edge 38.14393.1066.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393

MicrosoftWebDriver Version :

4.15063
Release 15063

Could you please tell if this is a version compatibility issue? Or I am doing something wrong here?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need use MicrosoftWebDriver Version: 
Release **14393** Version: **3.14393** | Edge version supported: **14.14393**

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

or update Microsoft Edge

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing out the version compatibility issue. Now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a Microsoft Edge Driver version equal to the version of the Edge brwoser in your system. To find the version number go to `Settings->About Microsoft Edge`. 
After downloading you need to change the name of the driver to `MicrosoftWebDriver.exe` from `msedgedriver.exe`. Then It will work :)

Answer (score 0):

@Prabodh Ghosh:
The code snippet you used seems to be OK. The only wrong is the version incompatibility of EdgeDriver and Windows.

1. Check the Windows Version and build you are using:
   1.1 Open Run pop up -> Type dxdiag and press Enter or click OK
   1.2 Observe the Windows Build # as like as image below:
   [image]
2. Now open a browser and visit https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/
3. Download the correct Microsoft WebDriver server version for your build. (I downloaded Release 15063 of MS WebDriver as my Windows 10 Build is 15063)
   [image]
4. Now write and apply the following code snippet of Selenium Java:

   System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "D:\Selenium_RiponAlWasim\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
   driver = new EdgeDriver();

Or, you can write the code by using DesiredCapabilities as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "D:\\Selenium_RiponAlWasim\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.edge();
driver = new EdgeDriver(capabilities);
```